# How to get id of the modern experience id in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

How to get the id of the folder in  modern experience 
Example:https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sample/Lists/Special%20characters%20list/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2Fsample%2FLists%2FSpecial%20characters%20list%2F%2525

I want this id  using Csom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell code**:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$SiteURL="https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sample"
$UserName="lz@xyz.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "abc"
$listName ="Special characters list"

$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,$SecurePassword)

#Bind to Site Collection
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = $Creds

$list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$q = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$q.ViewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>'
$items = $list.GetItems($q)
$ctx.Load($items)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
foreach($item in $items)
{
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor green "id: " $item["FileRef"]
}
```

**C# code**:

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/sample";

var login = "lz@xyz.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "abc";

var listName = "Special characters list";
var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
var q = new CamlQuery();
q.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
var items = list.GetItems(q);
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("id: "+ item["FileRef"]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```